# How to translate this English idiom into German: "to have something in the palm of your hand"

Tags: idiom

How do you translate 'to have something in the palm of your hand' into German as an idiom? The English would mean to be in control of something.

I was told 'in seiner Handfläche haben' is too literal, but they didn't provide an alternative either.

Comment: A phrase with similar meaning would be "etwas im Griff haben". It can mean something like "to have control over something", but more like "to have a grip on something", "to have a handle on something", not "to have something in the palm of one's hand".

Comment: @Henning Kockerbeck: dict.cc lists *jdn. fest im Griff haben*. It also lists the more literal *jdn. voll unter Kontrolle haben*. The Wiktionary entry is [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_someone_in_the_palm_of_one%27s_hand) but it only lists a translation into Italian. I'd be glad to add a German one if there is agreement on what it should be. I don't think the idiom is very common, at least not any more.

Comment: @RDBury To me, it increasingly looks like there's an important difference whether we're talking about a person or an object in the palm of somebody's hand. Aleks asked about _something_, but from my experience the English phrase is mostly used as "to have _somebody_ in the palm of your hand". In German, "etwas im Griff haben" is much less sinister than "jemandem im Griff haben".

Comment: Please provide a full sentence. Idioms can translate different depending on context.

Comment: It is worth noting the similar English phrase "to have (something) eating out of the palm of my hand", which implies a docile relationship of the eater to the feeder, but not necessarily very much control.

Comment: Usually when one hears the phrase "in the palm of my hand", it is as a prelude to a tale of loss.  For example, "I had the whole deal in the palm of my hand, and then our funding didn't come through."

Comment: @BrianB Then it would mean something like "Ich hatte das Geschäft schon in der Tasche / in trockenen Tüchern".

Comment: I'm not sure that the phrase does really imply "control". I think of it as originally biblical (Isiaah?): God holds us in the palm of his hand, and the primary implication is that he protects us.

Answer (score 13):

There is a similar figure of speech in German, which just leaves out the palm:

> es in der Hand haben

It is usually used in statements such as "Sie hat es in der Hand." or "Du hast es in der Hand.", and it means it is up to <subject> how "it" will continue.

Comment: The connotations of the two phrases are a bit different, though. "To have something in the palm of your hand" has quite a dark vibe of control and domination. "Etwas in der Hand haben" speaks more of agency. The meaning is something like "it's up to you", "it's your choice (and nobody elses)". If you use either phrase with a person instead of an object, the meanings are closer. "Er hat seinen Nachbarn in der Hand" is relatively close to "He has his neighbor in the palm of his hand".

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck I cannot say anything about the possible connotations ot the English phrase. But the phrase "to have **something** in the palm of your hand" seems to refer to a thing, not to a person. Could you give an example making clear what you mean by the dark connotation?

Comment: This sounds the English "to have it in hand", but though they are literal translations of each other, I have the impression that the meanings are different.

Comment: @PaulFrost "To have something / someone in the palm of one's hand" implies _total_ control. Examples would be "She finally bought the last shares. Now she has the company in the palm of her hand" or "He knows his neighbor's dirty little secret. He has his neighbor in the palm of his hand". Most of the time, you can image the appropriate "muahahaha" with this phrase.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Thank you for the examples. But isn't in these "in der Hand haben" the adequate translation? "Jetzt hat sie die Firma (völlig) in der Hand"? And doesn't "Sie hat jemanden in der Hand" an extortionate touch?

Comment: @Henning Kockerbeck: I think would almost always be "to have **someone** in the palm of one's hand", though your example with the company does work. The degree of control may be accidental, for example "Naomi's grandparents spoil her terribly; she's certainly got them in the palm of her hand." While Naomi may be enjoying the situation, I don't see her going "muahahaha". One might also say Naomi has them "wrapped around her finger".

Comment: @PaulFrost As noted in the comments to the question, I'm getting increasingly convinced that in German there's a significant difference between "etwas in der Hand haben" (more neutral) and "jemanden in der Hand haben" (as you mentioned, with an extortionate touch). I see "etwas in der Hand haben" like for example "Er hat es jetzt selbst in der Hand ob er den Job bekommt oder nicht" ("it's in his own hands").

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck It would be worth to present your thoughts in an official answer.

Comment: Wow, I would say the opposite about the English. To me, "holding someone in the palm of your hand" indicates total care, like "Until we meet again, may God hold you in the palm of his hand." In fact, I have basically only heard this phrase referring (positively) to God.

Answer (score 6):

Aleks is asking about "to have *something* in the palm of one's hand", but to my knowledge the English phrase is typically used as "to have *someone* in the palm of one's hand". In German, there are similar phrases, but their subtext differs significantly when you use them with a person or an object.

O. R. Mapper already mentioned "etwas in der Hand haben". When used with an object, this phrase has a more or less neutral subtext. The meaning is something like "it's up to you", "it's your choice", "it's in your own hands".

> Er hatte es jetzt selbst in der Hand, ob er den neuen Job bekam oder nicht.

When used with a person, the phrase has a significantly darker, almost extortionate vibe:

> Sie kannte das kleine, schmutzige Geheimnis ihres Nachbarn. Damit hatte sie ihn völlig in der Hand.

There's a similar situation with the phrase "im Griff haben". Used with an object, "etwas im Griff haben" means something like "to have control over something", "to master something":

> Zuerst hatte sie Schwierigkeiten mit der neuen Maschine gehabt, aber nach einigen Tagen hatte sie alles im Griff.

When used with a person, it also gets somewhat sinister:

> Der persönliche Referent hatte den Senator völlig im Griff. Der Senator würde nie etwas tun, wovon ihm sein Referent abgeraten hatte.

Comment: "When used with a person, it also gets somewhat sinister:" - but not always. "Der Lehrer hatte den wilden Schüler im Griff." is not sinister.

Answer (score 3):

Either one of these invokes the same image:

- "Es in der Hand (zu) haben" - to be able to influence it, to decide it, to do it ...
- "Es im Griff (zu) haben" - be on top of it, be able to do it; it is easily done

The first is more in the context of being responsible or being allowed to do/decide/control something. The latter is more about ability and does not have the aspect of permission or control.

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the comments I agree that the German translation "Es in der Hand zu haben" might be a little too weak. I guess most of the time it fits but here are some other possibilities:

- etwas/ jemanden fest unter Kontrolle haben
- die Zügel in der Hand haben
- etwas/ jemanden in der Mangel haben

I feel like there is more but I cant think of it right now.